# create registration and login page in wordpress

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

I have a page called journal in my wordpress site. So my requirement is only the users which are registered with us should be able to access the journal page from site.
when users try to access journal page it should show login screen to them.
please guide

Answer (score 0):

you need to use membership plugins, there is lots of plugin for membership, I preferred membership-pro plugin. Read the documentation there is a setting option if user not registered or signing.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/
[image]

let me know if further problem.